# Strings command: 3 rows near.

Tags: linux, string, command-line

Im using the **strings** command on Ubuntu.

I want to analyze even the 3-4 rows where the word appear, someone can remember me the command for do that?

Comment: Your question doesn't parse. Perhaps you could add an example of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a particular word in a line from the 'strings' output, pipe the output to 'grep'. If you want the line-numbers where it occurs, use the '-n' flag.

`strings /bin/ls|grep -n strtoul`